# PTIJ: What happened to Reuven's tie?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

In telling the story of the sale of Yosef, the Torah says that Reuven suggested putting Yosef in the pit so that he could come back and save him later.

When Reuven came back to discover that Yosef was no longer there, [he said](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8232#v30):

> וַיָּ֥שָׁב אֶל־אֶחָ֖יו וַיֹּאמַ֑ר הַיֶּ֣לֶד אֵינֶ֔נּוּ וַֽאֲנִ֖י אָ֥נָה אֲנִי־בָֽא

Some say that the last word on the line is a *kri uktiv*, and it should say "עניבה", a necktie, and thus be read "He returned to his brothers and said, 'The boy is not with us, and where is my tie?'".

What was so special about Reuven's tie, and what happened to it?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 9):

R'euven was very protective of Joseph, even though he was also jealous of him. When he saw that Yaakov had given Joseph a nice striped jacket, he knew that something was missing. What person doesn't wear a tie together with a jacket? So, he lent Joseph his tie. Joseph would, thus, wear this tie whenever he wore the jacket.

So when he saw that Joseph was missing, it wasn't really a comment of surprise when he said. "Where's my tie?" It was more a statement of "fact" like saying, "the kid is missing, and, now, so is my tie!" (i.e., I lent it to Joseph, and now I may not get it back.)

Answer (score 8):

Reuven had left his tie behind because he was [going to wear sackcloth](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.37.29.1) in teshuva for his sin, and who wears a tie with sackcloth?  He left it with his brothers for safekeeping.

When he came back and saw Yosef missing, Reuven assumed that somebody else had pulled Yosef out of the pit (which is what some mefarshim, like [Chizkuni](https://www.sefaria.org/Chizkuni%2C_Genesis.37.28), say is what actually happened).  He thought his brothers would be just as surprised as he was.

When he noticed his tie missing, he realized that the brothers were the ones who had used the tie as a rope to get Yosef out of the pit.